# Sync a directory to Google Drive from outside the Drive folder

Tags: macos, file, filesystems, backup, symlink

**Context**

I am trying to have the resources directory of a project sync itself to Google Drive as a means of backup, without having to physically move it into the Drive folder, and while maintaining full tab completion and access via the terminal from within the project. **I'm on OS X**.

The project is stored in a separate portion of my filesystem dedicated to GitHub repos, but I don't want to store all of the media (it's a vision project) on GitHub.

Now, the simplest solution is to alias the resources directory, move the original to the Drive Folder and access it via the alias within the project. However, accessing the resources via an alias in the terminal appears to break not just tab completion, but actual access to the media...

Eg: `./program input=resources/video.mp4`

...where resources is an alias of `Drive/resources`, fails. And I'm afraid my understanding of aliases, symlinks and hardlinks isn't deep enough to see why.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to sync the a directory to drive without physically moving the original directory to `Drive/`, such that I can leave my project filesystem untouched.

OR

2. Is there a way to maintain normal path behaviour and tab completion with an aliased directory? eg: `./program input=Project/res_alias/video.mp4`. If so, the Drive issue is null and void.